# Without login session no one can access controller in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

I want to direct all users to the login page who don't have sessions.

I created a construct function inside my controller. But it's not working. Here is my code:

```
 public function __construct(){
    $session = session();
    if($session->username != true){
        return redirect()->to('/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're currently checking if your username is not true, what happens if you check if its false? `if(!$session->username){}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. In Codeigniter 4, __construct method doesn't work. That's why it's not working. Instead of I used Codeigniter 4 filters to redirect into the login page. Here is my Codeigniter filter code:

```
 class LoginFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
       if(!session()->username){
        return redirect()->to(base_url('login'));
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hade you tried:

```
if($session["username"] != true){
```

what about

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
```